# Setup SWFAddress Flash with dynamic content (xml)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, swfaddress

i've been looking for long time a way to setup swfaddress with flash as3, assuming that the content is pulling from an xml.
Basicaly, i got an xml that contain reference of SWF i load in my main.swf

What i already can do :

Each time a swf has been loaded 
- the html page title change via setTitle()
- the url change via setValue();

What i cannot do :
- changing the url on the browser does not load the wanted swf

Has my content is totaly dynamic, i cannot use the swich / case method.

Please can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the JavaScript included on your host page? Remember that you must listen for the SWFAddressEvents before you listen for any user events at all.

Comment: Hello, everything works great in a static way, i mean for exemple the above code works
    SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, addressChange);

    function addressChange(event:Event)
    {
        switch (SWFAddress.getValue())
 {
   case '/Test1':
   // Do the thing i want to do
   break;
 }}

Comment: You dont HAVE to use a switch() case. You can simply call an action with the value of the event. For example: new ViewObject(event.getValue()){ and then render the value to the screen.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the method.

Comment: all Im saying is you dont have to use a switch case, you can still use the value of the event.

Comment: I know but impossible to make it work. What i've tryed is search for an entry in my array that match SWFAddress.getValue().split("/").join(" ")... but it doesn't do nothing.

Comment: better than getValue().split("/").join(" ") would be getValue().substr(1); which will return everything after the slash. Im currently using that.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip. Do you have a code exemple i can study using SWFAddress with xml content?

Comment: Not one that I can pass along, sorry.